# PHPMyAdmin SQL query field only allows uppercase letters to be entered

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, uppercase, lowercase

I've only been using MySQL for a short time. When on the "SQL" tab, using the text input for queries is only allowing me to type in uppercase letters.

I can't think why this has happened as only yesterday it was working fine.

I've attached an image to show you what I mean.
[image]

A few things to note:

1. My caps lock is OFF
2. If I run a query like the one shown in the image it does in fact create the database with a lowercase name.
3. Similarly, If I was to press shift to create a capital - it does that fine too
4. I'm working off my MAMP localhost version 4.0.2

The issue is that I can't see my upper/lowercase characters while writing the query itself which means I may find it harder to accurately target certain elements of the database.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Is it as simple as changing a setting?

Comment: Can you try with a different web browser?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen anything like this, but I know the .ini file has a setting lower_case_table_names to set table names to lower case.  I do not know MAMP but certainly check the .ini file.  Also if you have not been using MySQL that long maybe change to EasyPHP (Apache, PHP and phpMyAdmin - works great for me.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! I am able to create uppercase and lowercase table names. I'm just not able to see the uppercase and lowercase parts as I'm typing the query. I had a look at the .ini file and couldn't see anything that would be causing the issue. I would change to EasyPHP but I need to use MySQL for an assignment.